# how to hide unwanted white space inside html

Tags: php, html, css

there is a white space in my html and I found it strange.

when I'm trying to load page with ajax this white space doesn't appear.
but when I include that page inside html, a `""` appears .

```
<div id="last_exam" class="white_board fleft">
    <?php if(@!empty($ypage['last_exam'])) @include_once($ypage['last_exam']); else { ?>
        <div class="sdiv" style="height:138px;">

        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

sdiv is a tag inside my second page.

my html debugger:

[image]

I tried to use `.sdiv:before` to hide that but nothing happened.

any Similar case?

Comment: `$ypage['last_exam']` is empty ?  whats the content of it ?

Comment: link of my 2nd page to include

Comment: There are problems when including a file saved with BOM, which creates extra white space. Could be it. See [here](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div id="last_exam" class="white_board fleft">
<?php
if(@!empty($ypage['last_exam']))
@include_once($ypage['last_exam']);
else
echo '<div class="sdiv" style="height:138px;"></div>';
?>
</div>
```